# Relation between Pfister forms in W(Q)

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, quadratic-forms

For $n$ a nonzero integer, is it possible to have a relation 
$$ n\langle\langle-1,-1\rangle\rangle=\sum_i n_i\langle\langle a_i,b_i\rangle\rangle$$ in $I^2(\mathbb Q)\subset W(\mathbb Q)$ (or maybe $W(\mathbb R)$ if you want), where $n_i\in\mathbb Z$ and the $a_i,b_i$ are positive rational numbers?

Comment: What's the meaning of $W(\mathbb R)$ and $I^2 (Q)$ ?

Comment: $W(k)$ is the Witt ring of the field $k$. $I(k)$ is the so-called fundamental ideal of $k$, i.e., the ideal of even dimensional forms on $k$. $I^n(k)$ is the $n$-th power of the fundamental ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible, neither in $W(\mathbb{R})$ nor in $W(\mathbb{Q})$ : if $a,b>0$ then $\langle\langle a,b\rangle\rangle$ is hyperbolic over $\mathbb{R}$ so is $0$ in $W(\mathbb{R})$, whereas $n\langle\langle -1,-1\rangle\rangle$ is nonzero if $n$ is nonzero. Since the equality cannot hold over $\mathbb{R}$, it cannot hold over $\mathbb{Q}$ either.

Generally speaking, deciding equality in $W(\mathbb{Q})$ is supposed to be easy : you just have to check equality in $W(\mathbb{R})$ and all $W(\mathbb{Q}_p)$, by Hasse-Minskowski's theorem. But $W(\mathbb{R})\simeq \mathbb{Z}$ through signature (easy to compute), and $W(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ is also easy to compute with explicit isomorphisms to finite rings (see Lam's book on quadratic forms for instance).